# How to improve procedural world generation performance

Tags: c#, performance, unity-game-engine, procedural-generation

I'm creating a minecraft-style game which is procedurally loaded. The world is built from chunk columns, which are stacks of 16 chunks. Each chunk is a cube made from 16x16x16 blocks, which are in turn made from quads (for performance reasons).

When my player moves around, I want the chunk columns within a certain radius to render. Each tick I check which chunk columns are within radius of the player, then render them. When this happens the world freezes for 1-2 seconds. I've changed this so each tick only renderes a single chunk instead of a whole chunk column. The game is freezing for around 0.5 - 1 seconds each time.

The code doing the rendering is here:

```
// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    StartCoroutine("Render");
}

IEnumerator Render()
{
    int radius = 2;
    Vector3 currentPosition = Camera.main.transform.position;
    Vector2 currentChunkPosition = new Vector2((float) Math.Floor(currentPosition.x / Chunk.size), (float) Math.Floor(currentPosition.z / Chunk.size));
    float chunkColumnDistance;

    for (int x = 0; x < world.Size.x; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < world.Size.y; y++)
        {
            chunkColumnDistance = Mathf.Sqrt((float) Math.Pow(x - currentChunkPosition.x, 2) + (float)Math.Pow(y - currentChunkPosition.y, 2));

            if (chunkColumnDistance <= radius)
            {
                for (int i = ChunkColumn.chunksPerColumn - 1; i > -1; --i)
                {
                    if (world.chunkColumns[x, y].chunks[i].rendered)
                    {
                        continue;
                    }

                   world.chunkColumns[x, y].chunks[i].Render();
                   yield return null;
               }
           }
        }
    }
}
```

I would always expect a small delay with each update, but not to the extent where it is noticeable to the player. I am currently running the rendering update as a coroutine but I'm not sure where to go from here. Can anyone suggest an imrovements.

For reference, the project is here: https://github.com/JoshPJackson/BlockGame/blob/master/Assets/Scripts/Game.cs

**EDIT:**

I've made a change so that I only render chunks which are within a certain radius of the player, rather than every chunk in the chunk column that are within the radius of the player. The performance is better, but still not quite there.

The updated code is:

```
IEnumerator Render()
    {
        int radius = 2;
        Vector3 currentPosition = Camera.main.transform.position;
        float chunkDistance;

        for (int x = 0; x < world.Size.x; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < world.Size.y; y++)
            {
                for (int i = ChunkColumn.chunksPerColumn - 1; i > -1; --i)
                {
                    chunkDistance = Vector3.Distance(currentPosition, world.chunkColumns[x, y].chunks[i].globalPosition);

                    if (chunkDistance <= radius * Chunk.size)
                    {

                        if (world.chunkColumns[x, y].chunks[i].rendered)
                        {
                            continue;
                        }

                        world.chunkColumns[x, y].chunks[i].Render();
                        yield return null;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Typically calculating square roots is a slow operation and best avoided in code that will run often and you need fast. Not totally familiar with render culling in unity, but this seems an inefficient approach in general.

Comment: Hi @rebusB. In what was is it inefficient? (I'm new to this sort of thing)

Comment: Rather than checking `Mathf.Sqrt(...) <= radius` (as in the first piece of code) try checking `...<= radius * radius`. But then think further, which operations are necessary and which can be avoided or simplified by rewriting the expressions.

Comment: I've changed this now to be `Vector3.distance(....) < radius`. Not sure how much difference this will make though

Comment: You're iterating over all the chunks in the world, so the size of the world will determine how fast things will render. Maybe start by iterating from x = position.x - radius to x = position.x + radius. And the same for y. That may save some precious time.

Comment: You could use taxi driver distance. That is, render a square instead of a circle. you can go from y and x = playerXY - r to playerXY + r. Maybe store the rendered chunks in a list and update it each time the player moves enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Digging into your project code and it looks like you are building the entire visible world every update. That is, you are creating new GameObjects for all the visible block quads *each frame* and then throwing them all away (hopefully, else you will have a huge memory leak) before starting all over again the next frame.

A more efficient approach would be to instantiate all your GameObjects once, after you define your world.chunksColumns.chunks and then use `SetActive(true)` or `setActive(false)` in your Block classes' render call. Then the code above should run much faster.

Comment: Thanks @rebusB. I will try this later and will accept it as the answer if it helps

Comment: @joshuajackson  Awesome! Thanks... what speeds are you getting? I've been learning UnrealEngine, but started with Unity.

Comment: Well @rebusB I kind of hit a roadblock shortly after this. Your idea above made the world load very fast when there was a small number of chunks. But now I've increased the number of chunks the game runs out of memory unless I serialize some chunks to text files and then load them when needed. The loading and saving has killed the performance, so I'm trying to fix that now :/

Comment: how big is the world? You may want to look at geometry instancing if Unity supports it.

Comment: technically infinite I guess, but I'm trying to load a radius of 3 chunks around the player